# How to store manually ordered rows in a database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question regarding the ability to manually order database content.

For example, I might have a table of content with the following fields: `id`, `sort_order`, `content`. On my website front end, I output this content sorted by `sort_order`, and want to be able to manually rearrange items by changing their relative `sort_order` values.

At the moment, every time I add an item to the MySQL database I set the value of `sort_order` to the same value as the auto incrementing `id`, so by default the items will output in the order they were created. I then allow users to incrementally move items up or down the list by switching with the item next to it, in which case I swap the `sort_order` with the `sort_order` value of the next / previous item.

Unfortunately, if I want to move an item a long way up the list then I have to click many times to keep switching an item until it gets to the top.

I want to implement an interface where I can drag and drop items to order them, and place them anywhere in the list. What’s the best way to handle this data? If my database were to have thousands of entries, it would be extremely inefficient to change the `sort_order` on the many items between the old and new position.

I was thinking of allowing decimals in the `sort_order` field, so if I try to move an item to between `sort_order` values of 3 and 4, that item’s `sort_order` would be set to 3.5. If I then moved an item between 3.5 and 3.6 it would become 3.55, and so on.

The problem then is that this has potential for some `sort_order` values to eventually become extremely long decimals, which I’m assuming isn’t ideal.

So basically… what’s the best / standard way of handling manual sorting of items in a database that could have thousands or even hundreds of thousands of entries?

Comment: You will have to update each record that is effected to bump their `sort_order` by 1 like `Update yourtable SET sort_order = sort_order + 1 WHERE sort_order >= {the sort_order of the moved record};` One line of SQL and everything is shifted for your moved record. I think it's questionable though that you would allow a user to sort on "hundreds of thousands" of records only because that Update statement is going to be a little slowish on a huge number of records. That is a bit beastly.

Comment: This is quite a popular request. It's standard behaviour for drag-drop interfaces